# DIV offsetWidth/Width/innerWidth returns zero in IE8 when window resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i have so many elements in my page. Please conside below DIV

```
    <div id="root">    
        ..................
    <div id="child1">
        .............
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        ...............
    </div>
</div>
```

The root div(#root) has some width based on the content when gets loaded.

when ever window gets re-sized repaint() function is called which is present in window resize function

```
$(window).resize( function () {
    repaint();
});
function repaint(){
    //width returns "0" in IE8 browser and other browsers working fine
    var width=$("#root").width() || $("#root").innerWidth() -> returns zero value in IE8
}
```

it returns width as "0" in IE8 browser but returns some width (960px) in IE9 /other modern browsers.

i don't know what is the exact cause for this issue.

**why it returns zero width when window gets resized.**

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Could be a browser rendering issue, try testing with a timeout

Comment: The #root div isn't closed in the code you pasted here.

Comment: I think, it's cause due to elements display/position CSS properties.

Comment: @Ishan i dont have css for root element.could you please explain it more? which css property will throws this error

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5LFXK/

This works in IE8. See the console (the layout is f***ed up).

```
$(window).resize( function () {
  repaint();
});
function repaint(){
//width returns "0" in IE8 browser and other browsers working fine
var width=$("#root").width();
console.log(width);

}
```

Comment: it's cause due to elements display/position CSS properties.

Comment: You see some CSS here ?

Comment: how you ran the jsfiddle in IE8 ? i can't run it in IE8 browser

Comment: Try with this one : http://jsfiddle.net/5LFXK/2/  (In IE 8 JsFiddle not working correctly, Here i only update  @enguerranws fiddle with some alert(), so if you change window size fiddle alert you for this event.)

Comment: You got no alert ? Or alert 0 ? If you got no alert, maybe you didn't activate JS in your IE.